# Add the CA signed client certificate to the Advance Rest Client

Tags: rest-client, advanced-rest-client

Hi I would like to add the CA signed Client certificate to the Advance Rest Client. So, How can i add the certificate to the advance rest client ?

Comment: I'm with the same problem. It looks like the solution is to just use PostMan instead.